# "uninitialized constant OpenSSL::PKey::EC" from Ruby on CentOS 6.6

Tags: ruby, openssl, centos, jwt, openid-connect

I have a Rails server application that uses the `openid_connect` gem.  When I attempt to run it on CentOS 6.6, I get:

```
uninitialized constant OpenSSL::PKey::EC
```

Here is the full stacktrace:

```
$ rails server
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/json-jwt-1.5.1/lib/json/jwk/jwkizable.rb:69:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant OpenSSL::PKey::EC (NameError)
    from /home/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/json-jwt-1.5.1/lib/json/jwt.rb:102:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/openid_connect-0.9.2/lib/openid_connect/response_object/id_token.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/openid_connect-0.9.2/lib/openid_connect/response_object.rb:7:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/openid_connect-0.9.2/lib/openid_connect/response_object.rb:6:in `each'
    from /home/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/openid_connect-0.9.2/lib/openid_connect/response_object.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/openid_connect-0.9.2/lib/openid_connect/connect_object.rb:52:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/openid_connect-0.9.2/lib/openid_connect.rb:85:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from /home/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /home/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /home/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /home/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /home/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
    from /home/foo/tmp/openid_connect_sample/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /home/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /home/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

What does this mean and how I can I get past it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem stems from Red Hat's refusal to include (for fear-of-patent-litigation reasons) certain Elliptic Curve (EC) algorithms in CentOS' default build of OpenSSL.

**Note: According to [@Cal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33150757/650475), CentOS 6.7 does not have this issue.**

The `openid_connect` gem is dependent on the `json-jwt` gem, which uses one of those not-included algorithms.

Therefore, you need to rebuild a new version of OpenSSL that includes the needed algorithms.

These are the steps I followed (adapted from [here](https://www.ndchost.com/wiki/how-to-install-bitcoin-on-centos-7)) to build a new OpenSSL on my machine:

1. `cd /usr/src`
2. `wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.1l.tar.gz`
3. `yum install autoconf automake` (you probably already have these installed)
4. `tar zxvf openssl-1.0.1l.tar.gz`
5. `cd openssl-1.0.1l`
6. `export CFLAGS="-fPIC"`
7. `./config --prefix=/opt/openssl shared enable-ec enable-ecdh enable-ecdsa`
8. `make all`
9. `make install`

Now, your Ruby is probably still linked against the old OpenSSL library, so you'll need to rebuild it to link to the new one.

**Are you using `rvm`?**  Then great!  Any new Rubies you install will build against the new OpenSSL.  `rvm remove` your Ruby and re-install it (or simply install a different ruby version).

**Not using `rvm`?** Then I guess you'll need to rebuild Ruby the traditional way.  But you probably already know how to do that, right?  If not, you'll need to look in a different tutorial, because we can't cover that here.

Now reinstall `bunder` and do a `bundle install`, and your `rails server` should now run successfully.

(If anyone has corrections or clarifications to offer, please leave a comment and I'll make edits as necessary.)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem with CentOS 6.6.  But I didn't want to recompile a custom openssl and ruby to fix this.  I didn't take very good notes because I tried so many things, but it appears that an update to all of the latest & greatest packages to CentOS 6.7 solves the problem.

Here are a few relevant package versions I have:

```
openssl098e-0.9.8e-18.el6_5.2.x86_64                                                            
openssl-1.0.1e-42.el6.x86_64                                                                
openssl-1.0.1e-42.el6.i686
openssl-devel-1.0.1e-42.el6.x86_64
glibc-2.12-1.166.el6_7.3.x86_64
kernel-2.6.32-573.7.1.el6.x86_64
```

After updating these packages, rebooting, and reinstalling my bundle the json-jwt gem worked perfectly.

This was our production machines, and I believe the ruby standard libs were compiled from source, then created as a custom RPM.

Our build server uses RVM, and this ended up being more of a pain.  The RVM installer kept pulling binaries for centos, and the same failure came back again.

```
Found remote file https://rvm.io/binaries/centos/6/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p484.tar.bz2
```

I forced a source recompile like this:

```
rvm reinstall --disable-binary ruby-1.9.3-p484
```

And I noticed a very wonderful looking message:

```
 #applying patch .rvm/patches/ruby/ssl_no_ec2m.patch.
```

That patch file has some C macro conditions that appear to exclude some EC related code.

And that worked!  I also noticed that ruby's openssl.so has a lot of EC related symbols in it.  The previously packaged centos ruby did **not** have these:

```
$ cd ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux
$ strings openssl.so |grep _EC
PEM_write_bio_ECPKParameters
i2d_ECPKParameters
PEM_read_bio_ECPKParameters
d2i_ECPKParameters
PEM_write_bio_ECPrivateKey
i2d_ECPrivateKey_bio
i2d_EC_PUBKEY_bio
PEM_write_bio_EC_PUBKEY
PEM_read_bio_ECPrivateKey
PEM_read_bio_EC_PUBKEY
d2i_ECPrivateKey_bio
d2i_EC_PUBKEY_bio
OPENSSL_1.0.1_EC
EVP_PKEY_assign_EC_KEY
OP_SINGLE_ECDH_USE
```

If I had to guess, the recompile against my new openssl 1.0.1 package must have triggered some C macros that opened up some kind of alternative algorithm that isn't legally protected.

If you check your openssl.so for symbols and it doesn't have all of these _EC related stuff, that's probably an issue.

Comment: Good to know.  I was using 6.6.  I'll update my question/answer to note the version.